# <audio> tags rewind

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I can successfully embed the audio tag into my websites and play them. Unfortunately setting the currentTime to zero throws an error in every web browser I try.

How do I rewind the audio clips to the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource has to be seekable or it will throw an exception if you try to set the currentTime attribute. Also, you only want to set currentTime to the range specified by the seekable attribute. The range starts at startTime and goes to duration.

Comment: seekable is simply an attribute I must set then? Also do you know a good html5 reference for these things yet?

Comment: No, seekable is set to a TimeRanges object when the metadata for the resource is downloaded. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-seekable

My guess is your resource isn't seekable. Did you encode your resource?

Comment: I should also add that I just did a little test and Firefox doesn't even implement the seekable attribute yet, so you couldn't check that in all browsers anyway (Chrome does implement it.) Either way, if you set the currentTime to 0, it should work provided A. the resource is seekable and B. the resource meta-data has downloaded by the time you attempt to set currentTime.