# HTML5 audio will not play a second time in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

I am working on a web app where I need to play a word and sentence audio file. I'm using backbone to fetch and render content from the server. The audio files live on S3. When content is rendered, I play the word audio file, then sentence audio file. I also have a button for each so the word and sentence audio can be replayed.

My problem is that Firefox will not replay audio files after the initial play. When `playWord` and `playSentence` are called, nothing happens. The code words fine in Safari and Chrome.

```
  events: {
   "click a#play-sentence":     "playSentence",
   "click a#play-word":         "playWord"
  },


  // render markup when model has synced with server
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ exam: this.model }));
    this.cacheMedia();

    return this;
  },


  // save audio objects. play word then sentence
  cacheMedia: function() {
    this.audioWord = this.$el.find('#audioWord').get(0);
    this.audioSentence = this.$el.find('#audioSentence').get(0);

    this.audioWord.addEventListener('ended', function(){
      this.currentTime = 0;
    }, false);

    this.audioSentence.addEventListener('ended', function(){
      this.currentTime = 0;
    }, false);

    var view = this;
    var playSentence = function() {
      view.audioSentence.play();
      view.audioWord.removeEventListener('ended', playSentence);
    };

    this.audioWord.addEventListener('ended', playSentence);
    this.audioWord.play();
  },


  // play sentence audio
  playSentence: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.audioWord.pause();
    this.audioWord.currentTime = 0;

    this.audioSentence.play();
  },


  // play word audio
  playWord: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.audioSentence.pause();
    this.audioSentence.currentTime = 0;

    this.audioWord.play();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to reload the audio file before playing it, like this.audioWord.load() and then this.audioWord.play() ?

Comment: I had this problem with some browsers in a project I did a year ago. To get all of them to work I ended up having to do a reload of the audio source and then play it again, as @RoumelisGeorge has suggested.

Comment: The SoundJS library has no issue playing a sound multiple times in FireFox without reloading. Support for HTML audio and WebAudio. http://createjs.com/#!/Demos/SoundJS/Audio-Test-Suite (click HTML audio only at the top, it defaults to web audio)

Comment: possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004437/why-isnt-my-audio-rewinding

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm using AWS S3 with an expiring url so `.load()` works, but only if the user clicks for multiple plays while the download url is still valid. The `.load()` after each play is not a great solution, but we haven't had any users complain yet.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is call `.load()` in both cases, i.e. `playWord()` should only need `this.audioWord.load();` and `playSentence()` should only need `this.audioSentence.load()`;.